# Access Django Rest API using Azure access token and SimpleJWT access token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, azure-appservice, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, azure-service-principal

Need just hint, tried all possible ways.

Any approach is highly appreciated.

**Problem statement**: access jwt authenticated django rest api using azure ad access token in postman and local app. django app is hosted on azure app service.
**Challenge**: pass two token with different header values in authorisation header such that azure token is also reader with django jwt token.

A. All possible authorisation in postman.

B. Different authorization keys and header values in django jwt settings

1. I've deployed my django application on azure app service.
2. I'm using JWT authentication for all rest API's.
3. I've an azure directory and service principal linked to azure web app.
4. In postman,

I can get access token from azure active directory(using clientID, Secret, resource, etc.) and use the same token to call django rest api.

5. I can easily access unauthenticated API just by using azure access taken in authorization bearer header.
6. For JWT authenticated API, I'm not able to use them (crud operation) as none of my approach is working.

Azure access token header value : Bearer

Django JWT token header value: Bearer, Token, JWT.

---- EDIT ----

Django application will server as a backend to client applications. Thus client application have to generate azure token and provide while calling django app API. But django application API's are also authenticted with JWTAuthentication, thus 2 tokens have to provided.

**Problem**
Both Tokens have to be provided in 'Authorisation' key to use with HTTP_AUTHORISATION.

**INFORMATION**
JWT packages: simplt_jwt
simplt_jwt,django version: latest
client: react-js webapp, swift ios mobile app
resources: azure app service, azure active directory with service plan

*django website is used as a backend for webapp and mobile app.*

To elaborate, some images are added:
Need to use this architecture (api endpoint with jwt authentication):
Call an API with JWT authentication header value in (Bearer, Token, JWT), and have to provide Azure access token withheader value as (Bearer).
Both Tokens have to be provided in authorisation header.
[api endpoint with jwt authentication][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Uvf.png

- Called an API(wihout django JWT authentication) using only azure access token and was able to get response.

---

Correct me if I'm using some wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Add another custom backend and verify your Azure token by its public key:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/

And add it next to your SimpleJWT auth backend.

In your settings.py file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        # add your azure backend here
        'your_app.auth_azure_backend.AzureAuthentication',
    )
    ...
}
```

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend

class AzureAuthentication(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None):
        azure_token = request.headers['AzureToken']  # you can use custom headers or just use `Authentication` with Bearer token. Django will go through every backend to verify it.
        decoded = jwt.decode(azure_token, public_key, algorithms=["RS256"])
        # return user instance based on decoded data from Azure
```

If you can decode without error that means your token is generated by Azure AD.

You can follow this question to get your public key https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/793793/azure-ad-validate-access-token

Comment: Is azure access token readed by the app service to authenticate.

Comment: Because only after passing azure access token in authorisation header, I'm able to get n API which is not authenticated by the backend.

Comment: @SajalTiwari yes, you need to add custom authentication class to your AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS settings, follow the django docs link

Comment: Thank you for your generaous response, but my scenario is different. Can you please check comments.
My django app is not reading azure access token, it is used by a service principal allowing me to bypass azure OAuth. 
Client Application have to provide azure accesstoken and django jwt token(generated using simple-jwt pakage, azure access token was provided in Authorize bearer token)

Comment: P.S: I tested with one API wihtout any authentication & permission class and was able to get response(provided azure access token in authorisation header).

Comment: why do you need both tokens tho, you can just use 1 Azure token instead. The way the DRF authentication backend work is it will iterate through every backend and if you bypass 1, you are authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, if wrong please provide feedback.

I have create an authentication class inheriting JWTAuthentication class. And reading custom headers in request.headers. this way I can provide multiple tokens in a request.

Actually, My application is hosted on azure app service. So have to authenticate send also application have some inbuilt authentication to manage user access, thus need token for the same.